# Add event in the head of the queue

Tags: javascript, events

I have already defined onclick event. I want to add additional call back function, that will be invoked BEFORE already defined callback.

- How to add an event in the head of the queue for concrete event type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you working with jquery framework ? I'm currently working with extjs and i found a class you can use or copy

Lets see on http://extjs.com/deploy/dev/docs/ Ext > EventManager > removeAll()

> removeAll( String/HTMLElement el ) :
>   void Removes all event handers from an
>   element. Typically you will use
>   Ext.Element.removeAllListeners
>   directly on an Element in favor of
>   calling this version. Parameters: el :
>   String/HTMLElement The id or html
>   element from which to remove the event
>   Returns: void

I think You can set the tag `body` as HTMLElement to shut down all events. (not tested sorry)

Download here http://extjs.com/products/extjs/build/ > select jquery adapter if you are working with jquery > extcore will suffice (it contain EventManager.js ).

On the other way, like crescentfresh (answer n°4), i made this sample code to apply to all node events :

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); // collect your nodes however
for(var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
     var node = nodes[i];
     Ext.EventManager.removeAll(node);
    }
}
```

Please let me know if you have trouble using extjs i can help, and vote for me if my answer is useful.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `attachEvent` for IE you cannot guarantee the order in which events are fired. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536343(VS.85).aspx

> If you attach multiple functions to
>   the same event on the same object, the
>   functions are called in random order,
>   immediately after the object's event
>   handler is called.

(I actually have seen that events are called in reverse order, not random). Anyway, libraries generally tend to use `attachEvent` deep down, so you're stuck with the same problem.

Having said that, if you can inspect a node for it's 'click' handlers (eg you have an "onclick" attribute setup on your node in your markup), then you *can* put "yours" ahead of "theirs":

```
var nodes = document.getElementsByTagName('*'); // collect your nodes however
for(var i=0; i < nodes.length; i++) {
    var node = nodes[i];
    if(!node.onclick)
        continue;

    // At this point we have a node with an "onclick" attr.
    // Hijack onclick to do something else first.
    var original = node.onclick;
    node.onclick = function() {
        doSomethingElse();
        return original.apply(this, arguments);
    }
}
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446892/how-to-find-event-listeners-on-a-dom-node#447106) for how to inspect the a node's events in other libraries (if you are using one). You may be able to use it to `doSomethingElse()` with those libraries too.

Answer (score 1):

Super. That made me look into jquery doc and I've found that combining crescentfresh's solution with jQuery's unbind() method (an analog of Extjs.removeAll()) will solve my issue.

So, at the end I have this:

```
this.onclick = function( e ) 
        if ( /*trigger clause*/ true ) { 
          //cancel all events
          $(this).unbind();
          return false;
        } else {
          //continue processing  
          return original ? original.apply(this, arguments) : true;
        }
      }
```

Thanks for advices guys!

PS What the jerks have made this awful reply editor??! It's a headache to paste some code here.

PPS Unfortunatelly I can't vote for two replys and I can't raise useful mark for your reply due to lack of reputation and I can't mark more than one answer acceptable. So, please forgive me. Stupid forum engine, but really cool people here

Answer (score 0):

[addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Element.addEventListener) lets you add another event. Note that in IE you will have to use attachEvent.

This will not let you define the order of the events - appearently you [can't predict the order the events will be fired in](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_advanced.html). So if you really want a predictable event queue for an event, you will have to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop the default action of an event with [preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.preventDefault) or stop the propagation of nested event with [stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation) to let only your specific event fire.

But pause or delay an event natively without using [setTimeout()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout), stopping, saving his state and re-firing later in the queue is impossible.

- [Here is an excelent explanation on
  how events works in javascript](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/timing-and-synchronization-in-javascript/)
- [And a note on how the timer
  works.](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/)

Answer (score -2):

You can simply stop an event listeners by simply load this sample function with correct params :

```
   function removeEvent(obj,type,fn){
  if(obj.removeEventListener) obj.removeEventListener(type,fn,false);
  else if(obj.detachEvent){
    obj.detachEvent("on"+type,obj[type+fn]);
    obj[type+fn]=null;
    obj["e"+type+fn]=null;
  }
}
```

Also, you can fire à setTimeout within the event that kill other listeners and re-enable listener one by one, externally or with an other setTimeout.

A library to debug events, maybe useful.